# in spark dataframe - how to map one column who`s type is List

Tags: apache-spark-sql

```
val df1 = Seq(
("a",2,"c"),
("a",2,"c"),
("a",2,"c"),
("b",2,"d"),
("b",2,"d")
).toDF("col1","col2","col3").groupBy("col2").agg(
      collect_list("col1").as("col1"),
      collect_list("col3").as("col3")
    )
df1.show
```

output:

```
+----+---------------+---------------+
|col2|           col1|           col3|
+----+---------------+---------------+
|   2|[a, a, b, b, a]|[c, c, d, d, c]|
+----+---------------+---------------+
```

How can I get the following table?(Concatenate the column names on the left side of each element in the list)

```
+----+---------------+---------------+
|col2|           col1|           col3|
+----+---------------+---------------+
|   2|[col1-a, col1-a, col1-a, col1-b, col1-b]  |  [col3-c, col3-c, col3-c, col3-d, col3-d]|
+----+---------------+---------------+
```

Comment: is that | required or can it be just an array overall?

Comment: @chinayangyongyong, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried to solve this using below approach-

### 1. Read the input

```scala
val df1 = Seq(
      ("a", 2, "c"),
      ("a", 2, "c"),
      ("a", 2, "c"),
      ("b", 2, "d"),
      ("b", 2, "d")
    ).toDF("col1", "col2", "col3").groupBy("col2").agg(
      collect_list("col1").as("col1"),
      collect_list("col3").as("col3")
    )
    df1.show(false)
    df1.printSchema()
```

Output-

```
+----+---------------+---------------+
|col2|col1           |col3           |
+----+---------------+---------------+
|2   |[a, a, a, b, b]|[c, c, c, d, d]|
+----+---------------+---------------+

root
 |-- col2: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- col1: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- col3: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

### 2. Use [Transform](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#transform) function to process array values

```scala
 val transform = (str: String) => expr(s"TRANSFORM($str, x -> concat('$str-', x)) as $str")
    val cols = df1.schema.map(f => if (f.dataType.isInstanceOf[ArrayType]) {
      transform(f.name)
    } else expr(f.name))

    df1.select(cols: _*).show(false)
```

Output-

```
+----+----------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+
|col2|col1                                    |col3                                    |
+----+----------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+
|2   |[col1-a, col1-a, col1-a, col1-b, col1-b]|[col3-c, col3-c, col3-c, col3-d, col3-d]|
+----+----------------------------------------+----------------------------------------+
```

Comment: added link of the documentation in the answer. can you please upvote + accept this if it helps

Comment: There are quiet a few of functions which are there in the `FunctionRegistry` but not in the `functions` object. They are added in the `functions` object in spark-3 - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-27297. Now you can accept + upvote, no?

Comment: how to find all built-in functions
1 https://spark.apache.org/  
2 click Documentation
3 click latest
4 API Docs
5 SQL,Built-in Functions

Comment: sorry i can not upvote,because "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."